# Python pattern matching function for nested list

Tags: python, algorithm, pattern-matching, matching

I'm trying to create a pattern matching function which looks through a nested list which contains books, and each book consists of:

- author
- title

So I want to search through this:

```
books = [['author', ['elon', 'musk']],
        ['title', ['book', 'one']],
      
        ['author', ['elon', 'tusk']],
        ['titel', ['book', 'two']]]
```

And my pattern matching function has some defining variables:

- '&' means it matches with exactly one element
- '--' means it can match with multiple elements

Here are some test cases:

```
search1 = [['author', ['elon', '&']],
           ['title', ['book', '&']]
# Explanation:
# Author: elon SOMETHING     -->     match with both books
# Title: book SOMETHING      -->     match with both books, return both


search2 = ['--', 
          ['title', ['book', 'one']]]
# Explanation:
# Author: -- means ALL authors
# Title: book one     --> should match with book one

#-- Run cases
match(search1, books)
match(search2, books)
```

Here is my current code which I'm having trouble connecting to the book searching algorithm:

```
def match(seq, pattern):
if not pattern:
    return not seq
elif pattern[0] == '--':
    if match(seq, pattern[1:]):
        return True
    elif not seq:
        return False
    else:
        return match(seq[1:], pattern)
elif not seq:
    return False
elif pattern[0] == '&':
    return match(seq[1:], pattern[1:])
elif seq[0] == pattern[0]:
    return match(seq[1:], pattern[1:])
elif type(seq[0]) == list and type(seq[0]) == list:
    if not match(seq, pattern):
        return False
else:
    return False
```

My question is, how can I implement something that can return the correct book or multiple books if that is the case? This function works for generic pattern matching but I'm having trouble making it work for this list of books and searching for author or a title. What can I add to make it work?